# Input corrupted on Windows 10 after 1083 update: ASCII chars are replaced with �

Tags: input, characters, ascii

Suddenly, likely due an update, input is corrupted for ASCII chars. I am using Windows 10 (Version 1803, Build 17134.112).

Usually if I write left Alt + 254 on numeric keyboard I got black square ■ but now I am getting replacement character �. Similar applies to other ones.

Any solutions?

Comment: What OS? What update?

Comment: @Spiff: Updated.

Comment: ■ is what I get when I type in Alt+254 so your updated Windows to version 1803 and then now when you type in Alt+254 now you get the � character instead? Have you already rebooted the PC just in case it's something simple or else wonder what language your system is setup with exactly?

Comment: This applies to all chars from 128 to, it seems, 255. I am using Czech and secondary English. You can see on https://www.asciitable.com that 125 is normally } and 254 is ■.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause was in the setting that I set some day. Specifically, “**Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support**”.

[image]

Comment: Huh, that's an interesting setting. (Good idea a few decades late?)

Comment: @grawity: I dunno what that should do but definitely on my Windows 10 settings this beta feature works bad.