# Alt-codes changed? (Win7 ⇒ Win10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, upgrade, alt-code

I used to use alt-codes a lot in windows 7, but i recently updated it to windows 10 (19 days ago, today). Now, whenever i type alt+(code), as i used to, i can't get any of the characters i used to get before. it's like everything changed, and i can't find any references of these changes.

additionally, trying to find the "offset" (i guessed it got offset because of the "commands" alt codes that are usually used by machines, like printers?) resulted in a lot of the results looking like a black diamond symbol with a question mark on it. this thing: �

i understand now that alt-code does work for most people on windows 10, the same way it used to work in windows 7 for me. so, am i missing fonts? i don't understand what's happening. it's been one headache over the other ever since i upgraded. it's almost like a complete downgrade from windows 7. and the worst part is, when i tried to install it at a different drive, the installation completely ignored my choices and replaced my previous OS. i really want to not hate windows 10, but it's leaving me no choices

edit: for clarity, these are what i used the most:
left alt + 3 used to give me a heart
left alt + 13 and 14 used to give me musical notes
left alt + 7 and left alt + 9 used to give me bullet points (one filled, the other unfilled - forgot which is which right now)
among others, like diacritic symbols such as é (alt+130)
now this is usually what i get: � (it looks like a black diamond with a question mark for me)

edit 2: adding `EnableHexNumpad`  to the registry didn't work, whether elevated or not

Comment: I assume you rebooted or logged off/on after setting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\EnableHexNumpad`?  In what application(s) are you trying to use these codes?  If you open PowerShell, type `Get-Culture`, and press Enter what does it display?  The codes you listed all work for me on Windows 10 v2004 with `EnableHexNumpad` enabled, though I'd note I see no difference between Left Alt + 9 and Right Alt + 9.

Comment: Also, if you press Alt + 2665, Alt + 266a, Alt + 266b, Alt + 2022, Alt + 25cb (note this is a "white circle"; Alt + 25e6 is the much smaller "white bullet"), or Alt + e9 (remembering to press the Numpad `+` key before each code), does anything look familiar?  My understanding is `EnableHexNumpad` specifically enables input of Unicode codes (values greater than decimal `255`), so that might not be relevant for the smaller codes you're used to.

Comment: heya @BACON - sorry i took so long to read this, i've been trying to resolve another pressing error i keep getting on my computer and network. it's still not fully resolved, but it's usable enough for now.

answering your questions:

Comment: i have rebooted many times yes lol  
  
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/560138667059052555/748593244908290139/unknown.png this is what it shows when i type Get-Culture in PowerShell  
  
i'm trying to use it in any application that allows for text entry. literally anywhere.  
  
alt+2665 gives me an "i"  
2022 gives me the usual �  
i can't enter any of the ones with a letter in them (or at least, nothing happens when i do)  
oh, pressing + with 2665 gives me ♥, and then ♪♫•○ (25e6 opens chrome's "customise and control" dropdown whenever i press the E, along with the Alt key)

Comment: ah, can't break line on here for some reason lol - i'm sorry for the run-on above xD - is there a way to enable the 255 characters that are entirely weird and now unknown to me? (having to remember the new codes is going to take a lot longer than just trying to find a copy-paste or alternative characters for it. heck, i didn't even know i could type letters until now lol)

Comment: I don't know what could cause this since it's the upper, Unicode codes that require additional effort to use, whereas the lower codes you want have [stayed the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).  The only thing I can think of is to open the `Start Menu` → type `Control` and select `Control Panel` to open the classic Control Panel → `Clock and Region` → `Region` → `Administrative` tab and make sure the system locale (`Language for non-Unicode programs`) is set to an appropriate value.

Comment: is this an appropriate value? https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/560138667059052555/748934583285841950/unknown.png

Comment: If you live or were raised in the UK and prefer speaking English then that is an appropriate value.  I think that `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support` option is your problem.  After enabling it on my `English (United States)` system the Alt codes in the question no longer produce the expected results.  See [Input corrupted on Windows 10 after 1083 update: ASCII chars are replaced with �](https://superuser.com/q/1332086/34985), [Windows 10 All alt codes and accentuated characters replaced by �](https://superuser.com/q/1411082/34985)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input corrupted on Windows 10 after 1083 update: ASCII chars are replaced with �](https://superuser.com/questions/1332086/input-corrupted-on-windows-10-after-1083-update-ascii-chars-are-replaced-with)

Comment: ok i'll try disabling the `Beta` thing and see if that works. hopefully it will - fingers crossed ( ◠ ‿◠)x

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews That's the solution! Add it as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Open registry editor as Administrator. Then navigate to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method` then in that key create a REG_SZ value named `EnableHexNumpad` and enter value 1.  Then reboot. Now you can enter alt codes in this syntax: right alt + plus button + hex code > release Alt key.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you meant by "then in that key create a REG_SZ value" - these are the only options i'm seeing: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/560138667059052555/726362195499417600/unknown.png

Comment: Reg_sz is string value.

Comment: ah ok, doing it now  
edit: btw, is right-alt and altgr the same thing? (is there a way to make it work like it used to, with the left alt, and without pressing +?)

Comment: Nope you need to press plus button

Comment: Since this value resides under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` root, it does not require administrator/elevated rights and should be set using the account for which the change is desired, which is not necessarily `Administrator`.  If one wanted to make the change for another account using an elevated process, it would instead have to be done through the appropriate hive under `HKEY_USERS`.

Comment: i should add that editing the registry didn't work, whether it was elevated or not ( ó ︿ò)

Comment: @WasifHasan for me this answer doesn't work